# Use R to make a barplot with bar colors determined by the height of the bar?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I would like to use R to make a barplot of ~100,000 numerical entries. The plot will be dense, which is what I want. So far I am using the following code:

```
sample_var <- c(2,5,3,2,3,2,6,10,20,...)  #Filled with 100,000 entries
barplot(sample_var)
```

The resulting plot is just what I want, but I would like to make a conditional formatting statement so that bars less than 5 will be black, bars >= 5 and <= 10 are green, and bars > 10 are red.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

**Update**: Looking at other solutions, *"easily"* was an overstatement. However, I'll leave my answer here for reference. Look at my other answer for a solution which does not require `ggplot2`.

---

You can use [the `ggplot2` package](http://ggplot2.org/) to produce that plot easily, using the [`bar` geometry](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/geom_bar.html) and `identity` statistic.

```r
library(ggplot2)

sample_var <- log(runif(10000) + 1)
ggplot(data.frame(x=seq(1:length(sample_var)), y=sample_var), aes(x=x, y=y, fill=y)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image: Resulting plot]

Answer (score 3):

If you want a simple answer, how about using the next vector as colors.

```
colors = as.character(cut(sample_var,breaks=c(0,5,10,20),labels=c('black','green','red')))
```

I do not quite remember where the inequalities are set in `cut()` but a simple help should clear everything.

But more importantly, do not make a barplot of 100000 entries.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [?ifelse](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ifelse.html) to create a vector of colors and include that in the call to `barplot`.  To make it possible for the colors to show up with so many bars, do not include a border around your bars (h/t to @musically_ut).

```
set.seed(1)     # this will allow you to get exactly the same data
                # this generates data to use for the example plot:
sample_var <- rpois(100000, lambda=5)  
cols       <- ifelse(sample_var<=5, "black", 
                     ifelse(sample_var<=10, "green", "red"))

barplot(sample_var, col=cols, border=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: You can get rid of the borders by setting them to `NA`: `barplot(sample_var, col=cols, border=NA)`

Comment: Great answer, can you please tell me what `lambda=5` does?

Comment: @jake9115, you wanted to make a barplot from 100k values, but you only provided the 1st 9 (no criticism), so I generated random numbers. It appears you wanted whole numbers where most will be <5, w/ fewer large values, so I generated them from the [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution). lambda is the parameter that controls the behavior of the Poisson distribution; it is the mean (& the variance).

Answer (score 2):

I find nested ifelse()'s ugly and so generally use `findInterval` to do selections from disjoint choices over a range of intervals. This is an alternative to @gung's answer:

```
set.seed(1)
sample_var <- rpois(100000, lambda=5)  
cols   <- c("black", "green", "red") [findInterval(samplevar, c(-Inf, 5, 10, Inf) ) ]

barplot(sample_var, col=cols, border=NA)
```

This has the advantage that it's very easy to change the cutpoints and colors. (no need to put in an image; it's identical to gung's image.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a separate answer which does not use `ggplot2` but the native R functions.

You can use the [palette functions](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/palettes.html) in R to generate a gradient to suit your granularity:

```R
sample_var <- log(runif(100000) + 1)

max.colors <- 1000
cols <- heat.colors(max.colors)

barplot(sample_var, col=cols[ max.colors - floor(max.colors * sample_var / max(sample_var)) ], border=NA)
```

[image: output plot]

There are some artefacts of condensing 100,000 lines into 800 or so pixels visible here. Some of the bars (periodically) are absent.